# Question downvote miscalculation?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I recently downvoted a poorly written question. The downvote was registered on the question, the change in reputation was documented on the user's page, the downvote count on my profile incremented, but I did not lose any reputation. Anytime I have downvoted in the past, the reputation change happened within 5 minutes, but it has been some time now and I have not seen any change. I have also received an upvote since then and that has registered fine.

Any ideas on why the downvote was not calculated into my total?

Comment: see [Should downvotes on questions be "free"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90324/148672)

Comment: I had missed that link that @Conrad was kind enough to post. Based on that link, it seems that this will be a permanent change? I do also see that "answer" is specified, albeit very subtly in the privileges section. Maybe that should be made more clear on that page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Downvotes on question do **not cost anything** to the downvoter.

*However,* downvotes on answers **do cost -1 rep** to the downvoter.